# Why does SQL UPDATE on JOIN updates every entry, but SELECT selects the correct entries

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I am trying to update a table based on another table. The following SQL updates every entry in `myTableA` when I would have expected it to update where `myTableB.active = true`:

```
  UPDATE
    myTableA
  SET
    myTableA.enabled = false
  FROM
    myTableA MTA
  FULL OUTER JOIN
    myTableB MTB
  ON
    MTA.user_id = MTB.user_id
  WHERE
    MTB.active = true
```

The above code updates 1000 entries int MTA, no matter the state of `MTB.active`. If, however, the first 4 lines are replaced with `SELECT *`, then it selects only 500 lines, as expected.

How can I update just the entries in `MTA` where `MTB.active = true`?

Comment: Current input and expected output please ?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) "*Do not repeat the target table as a from_item unless you intend a self-join*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to write this query is:

```
UPDATE myTableA MTA
  SET myTableA.enabled = false
  FROM myTableB MTB
  WHERE MTA.user_id = MTB.user_id AND MTB.active = true;
```

The references to `myTableA` in the `UPDATE` and `FROM` are different references.  So, your query is doing a `CROSS JOIN`.  In a `SELECT`, this is equivalent to:

```
FROM MyTableA update_A CROSS JOIN
     (myTableA MTA FULL JOIN
      myTableB MTB
      ON MTA.user_id = MTB.user_id
     )
    WHERE MTB.active = true
```

Clearly, the filter has nothing to do with the table being updated.

Two more points.  First, it is unlikely that a `FULL JOIN` would ever be used in an `UPDATE`.  Typically rows need to match for any update to occur.  Also, the `= true` is redundant.  `active` is clearly a boolean column, so it can be used as a complete boolean expression.

Comment: @ReactHelp . . . It is worth pointing out in a comment, at least, that this behavior differs from SQL Server, which also supports `FROM` clauses in `UPDATE` statements.  In SQL Server, your code would do what you expect -- except for the unnecessary outer join.

Comment: @ReactHelp . . . In the `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like below :

```
UPDATE myTableA MTA
  SET myTableA.enabled = false
  FROM myTableB MTB
  WHERE MTA.user_id = MTB.user_id AND MTB.active = true
```

Comment: Thank you. Where is MTA defined above? Is SQL smart enough to know that it is myTableA?

Comment: @ReactHelp MTA iq just an alias

Answer (score 1):

A correlated subquery might be good enough here:

```
update mytableA
set enabled = false
where exists (
    select 1
    from mytableB mtb
    where mtb.user_id = mytableA.user_id and mtb.active = true
)
```